# HAProxy hdr_dom(host) -i can't detect subdomain.subdomain.domain.com

Tags: haproxy

Hi Im trying to route different domain names listening of the same port to different backend using acl in haproxy. How i have a problem when one of the domain names has two subdomains. So my frontend config looks like this

```
bind *:80
mode http
acl is_kibana_prod hdr_dom(host) -i kibana.domain.com
acl is_kibana_nprod hdr_dom(host) -i non-prod.kibana.domain.com
use_backend backend_kibana_prod if is_kibana_prod
use_backend backend_kibana_nprod if is_kibana_nprod
default_backend backend_default
```

When I make a request to bar.bar.bar.com the request goes to backend_foo. Can anyone help me on this?

Actual logs:

```
172.17.0.1:54982 [21/May/2020:03:50:08.978] http backend_kibana_prod/kibanaprod 0/0/2/9/11 302 279 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {non-prod.kibana.domain.com} "GET / HTTP/1.1"

172.17.0.1:54982 [21/May/2020:03:50:08.989] http backend_kibana_prod/kibanaprod 0/0/0/32/37 200 85130 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {non-prod.kibana.domain.com} "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I need to use hdr(host) instead of hdr_dom(host)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration works for me in HAProxy 2.0. Below you can see I am capturing the Host header sent by the client within the request log and being sent to the appropriate backend for each host.

```
192.168.1.20:49506 [20/May/2020:23:29:33.869] fe_main backend_bar/s1 0/0/0/2/2 200 799 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {bar.bar.bar.com} "GET / HTTP/1.1"

192.168.1.20:49508 [20/May/2020:23:29:35.799] fe_main backend_foo/s1 0/0/1/6/8 200 2080 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {foo.foo.com} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

```
    bind *:80
    mode http
    http-request capture hdr(Host) len 32
    acl is_foo hdr_dom(host) -i foo.foo.com
    acl is_bar hdr_dom(host) -i bar.bar.com
    use_backend backend_foo if is_foo
    use_backend backend_bar if is_bar
    default_backend backend_default

backend backend_foo
   server s1 192.168.1.71:80

backend backend_bar
   server s1 192.168.1.122:80
```

Comment: that's weird cause that's not really happening in mine.

Comment: 172.17.0.1:54982 [21/May/2020:03:50:08.978] http backend_kibana_prod/kibanaprod 0/0/2/9/11 302 279 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {non-prod.kibana.domain.com} "GET / HTTP/1.1"

172.17.0.1:54982 [21/May/2020:03:50:08.989] http backend_kibana_prod/kibanaprod 0/0/0/32/37 200 85130 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {non-prod.kibana.domain.com} "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1"

actual logs from my haproxy